# Android: The specified child already has a parent

Tags: android, exception, parent-child, layout-inflater

I'm making a online store aplication that is available offline; hence the database stuff and a lot of other stuff.

I have a LinearLayout in the main xml file (home_screen_categories_products_linear_layout) which I inflate and add a layout from another file (product_details_layout). In this second layout (that represents the product details) I have another LinearLayout that contains the costumers opinions of the product (opinionsList) that I again inflate form another xml file
(opinion_layout).

And of course I get **"The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first."** exception.

I've encountered this before but managed to get around the problem; however in this case I can't think of how to do it.

I was expecting this exception but tried it hoping it would workd; I've read the other similar question here but didn't find a solution. Basically how do you inflate a layout in another layout that has already been inflated into another layout? (if that makes any sense)

Bellow is the code of the method that displays the product's details:

```
    LinearLayout parentLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.home_screen_categories_products_linear_layout);
    parentLayout.removeAllViews();
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.product_details_layout, parentLayout, false);

    TextView pretNou = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ProductDetailsNewPrice);

    ..........................

    String userName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_P_USER_NAME));
    String userRating = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_P_USER_RATING));
    String comments = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_P_COMMENT));
    String commentDate = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_P_DATE));

    LinearLayout opinionsParentLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.opinionsList);
    opinionsParentLayout.removeAllViews();
    View opinionView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.opinion_layout, parentLayout, false);

    if(userName.length()!= 0)
    {
        StringTokenizer nameSplitter = new StringTokenizer(userName,"{|}");
        StringTokenizer userRatingSplitter = new StringTokenizer(userRating,"{|}");
        StringTokenizer commentsSplitter = new StringTokenizer(comments,"{|}");
        StringTokenizer commentDateSplitter = new StringTokenizer(commentDate,"{|}");   

        while (nameSplitter.countTokens() >0 )
        {

            TextView user = (TextView) opinionView.findViewById(R.id.commentUser);
            user.setText(nameSplitter.nextToken() + " &#183; " + commentDateSplitter + " Rating:");

            ImageView userRatingIV = (ImageView) opinionView.findViewById(R.id.userRating);
            switch ( Integer.parseInt(userRatingSplitter.nextToken()) )
            {
                case 0 : userRatingIV.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.stars0)); break;
                case 1 : userRatingIV.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.stars1)); break;
                case 2 : userRatingIV.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.stars2)); break;
                case 3 : userRatingIV.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.stars3)); break;
                case 4 : userRatingIV.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.stars4)); break;
                case 5 : userRatingIV.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.stars5)); break;
            }

            TextView commentTV = (TextView) opinionView.findViewById(R.id.commentComment);
            commentTV.setText(commentsSplitter.nextToken());
            opinionsParentLayout.addView(opinionView);
        }
    }       

    parentLayout.addView(view);
```

Comment: please edit your posted code to only contain the stuff concerning view hierarchy. that way many more readers want to read through your code...

Comment: ok did it, hope I didn't remove more than it was needed

Comment: Why dont you inlcude the layouts into each other, so you dont have to puzzle them together in code?
http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html - this will clean up your code a lot :)

Comment: Yes, including layout  is a good practice. You can also  create custom views, which is very powerful. http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html
You can for instance delegate your text ad image setting to the custom view.

Comment: I was thinking of using <include> and inflate another empty layout but having a 4th empty layout just to inflate it is a bit distasteful to me. Any way to do this just with the main, the product details, and the comments xml files?

Comment: solved: had to move View opinionView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.opinion_layout, parentLayout, false); to always be called before addView().